# $(selector).mouseenter() Beginner

Tags: javascript, jquery, mouseevent

```
$('window').mouseenter(function(){
    mouseover = true;
}).mouseleave(function(){
    mouseover = false;
});
```

In the code above, would 'window' be correct syntax? If not, what would be the correct way to create a Boolean that tracks when the mouse in on the window and then off the window.

Comment: As stated in the answers, you only need quotes for HTML elements. For this reason, $('document') is also incorrect. Can anyone tell me any other common selectors without quotes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following is correct syntax

```
$(window).mouseenter(function(){
    mouseover = true;
}).mouseleave(function(){
    mouseover = false;
});
```

`$('window')` will try to look for a tag named window, not the window object.

Answer (score 0):

In Javascript `window` is an object, so your code will be

```
var mouseover;
$(window).mouseenter(function(){
  mouseover = true;
}).mouseleave(function(){
  mouseover = false;
});
```